# How to re-check SSL certificate even with exeption in browsers

Tags: security, ssl, domain, ssl-certificate, certificate

My SSL certificate has expired. I created a new one for my domain but after a few days. Certificate is now online and working but there is a problem at users side. When the certificate expired, users sometimes added "permanent exception" for my website so when I added new certificate, they still had the old exeption and did not see the new certification when they mouseover the "lock" icon on my website.

So is there any way how to make users to re-check certificate or remove old exception for their browsers without any huge setting options for them? Maybe some automated process?

Answer (score 0):

The new SSL certificate if it is signed by a trusted Certificate Authority, it will be valid as soon as it is installed. If users do not see the new certificate in the browsers, this means that  the new certificate is not installed on the server or there is a MITM attack, or they are accessing the wrong site.

The new certificate could be invalid if:

- it is singed for the wrong site (see the Subject and the Subject Alternative Name fields of the certificate).
- it is signed by a CA that is not trusted by the browser
- it is not in the valid period
- it was signed for a different purpose (e.g software signing, for a person), etc...

Edit1:
To see the information about the current certificate as it is presented by the web server, you can run:

```
echo ""|openssl s_client -connect example.com:443|openssl x509 -text -noout
```

Comment: Certificate is there and working ... Even with the exception it is there and users can see it when they choose to see the certificate. But when you moseover the site it is written that domain is not validated and there is an exeption for this site unless you remove exception for this site in settings like tools / options / advanced tab / view certificates / servers tab (Firefox) thats what I want to somehow change